# DNN Permissions - allow module access for all roles, except one?

Tags: permissions, dotnetnuke, dnn9

**When I deny the "Member Student" role access to a specific page, that page correctly denies those users, and shows a "you do not have access" page.**
[image: This works]

**However, when I deny the "Member Student" role access to a specific module,  the module still shows. Am I missing something obvious??  Using DNN v9.2**

[image: This doesnt work]

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set it to all the roles (registered users, un-registered users, unverified users) to have VIEW permissions and the Member Student role be denied the view permission to hide it.

I really feel like this USED to work the way you're expecting it to, but sometime in the past DNN permissions changed and perhaps Deny no longer trumps all other access.